# Javascript in Google Gadgets

Tags: javascript, google-gadget

I'm writing a simple gadget to use with google calendar.  I'm using iGoogle to test. However, no matter what I do I cannot seem to get javascript to run.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="hello world example" />
  <Content type="html"><![CDATA[ <div style="text-align:center"><a
    id="Riggs" title="My Photo Album" target="_blank" 
    href="http://picasaweb.google.com/doc.examples/ShelfBoy">
    <img border="0" alt="Photo" src="http://doc.examples.googlepages.com/Riggsie-OP.jpg" 
    title="Click Here."></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hi');
</script> 
]]></Content>
 </Module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the code exactly as you have it works for me, so I am not sure what problem you are having.

I have a [sample on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45vSB/) so you can see it in action.

If it does not show up with an alert box that says, "hi", then all I can guess is that your browser does not have Javascript enabled or is blocking alert messages.

If you want to test it yourself, you can use the [Google Gadgets Editor](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/tools.html#GGE).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Bribery always helps motivate.  I had been testing using a gadget in iGoogle.  In JsFiddle, I don't see where you put my code.. all I see is: <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/111256429991719942292/helloworld.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=200&amp;title=hello+world+example&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>.. Additionally, if I use the google gadgets editor that you linked to, how can I preview the results of the code?  Thanks again and enjoy my reputation! (in 6 hrs)

Comment: @Music Magi You can preview the results by doing File>Save>OK, File>Publish>OK>Add to my iGoogle Page or Add to a Webpage

Comment: Thanks again Peter.   I guess I was just an issue with iGoogle and I hadn't thought to use jsfiddle to test, but I'm on the right track now.